# Internet Explorer inline list for navigation menu

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, menu, html-lists

I'm having a problem with getting Internet Explorer to display my menu bar correctly. The menu items should be in an inline list across the page but they remain in a list going down the page with bullet points.

[Please see this fiddle for inspection](http://jsfiddle.net/xVwXq/).

I have been viewing in IE7 but as far as I'm aware the problem remains in IE9. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work with IE8/IE9 you will need IE html5 Shiv (just create elements with Javascript).
But be sure to make them  `display:block;` in your CSS!! 
 You can also have Google shiv to host it for you:[Google IE html5 Shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)
More about using  IE Shiv: [HERE](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/) 
But you can also make it yourself like this :

**[Your Fiddle HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/d9s4K/)**

```
<style type="text/css">
nav{
display:block;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.createElement("nav");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `<nav>`  HTML5 element. IE 8 and lower **do not** style unknown / unsupported elements.